# Select one value from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, echo

I have the code bellow, it's ok but I want to be able to use for example the 4th value extracted from the database, use it alone, not put all of them in a list, I want to be able to use the values from database individually. How do I echo them?

Edit: I was thinking to simplify things, to be able to add the values from database into one array and then extract the value I need from the array (for example the 4th - ordered by "order_id"). But how?

Right now I can only create a list with all the values one after the other..

(Sorry, I am new to this). Thank you for all your help..

```
<?php
include '../../h.inc.php';
$con = mysql_connect($db['host'],$db['user'],$db['passwd']);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM options WHERE Name LIKE 'x_swift%' ORDER BY order_id");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Values</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
//  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['VALUE'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
$array = array(mysql_fetch_array($strict));
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "value"? a whole record? just one field? just because you select more than you need doesn't mean you have to use everything you select ...

Comment: I just want one field from the whole table. The table is mixed with all kind of options. I have a set of rows with "name" starting with "dt_" and those rows have a "order_id" column from 1 to n, this order never changes. So I want to extract one field from the "value" column that has it's row "order_id" 4 for example.. (Rows from top to bottom, 1 to n)

Comment: i think you may be confusing yourself by making this harder than it is. if you just want to select the value in the `value` column of the row where `order_id` is 4, just do `select value from options where order_id = 4`. doing `select *` will select *all* columns, which doesn't sound like what you want. (by the way, naming a column `value` is VERY confusing.) also, when asking a question about mysql, it would be incredibly helpful for you to post the structure of your table so others can understand what you're talking about.

Comment: I understand, just one more question so I can clarify and get the best /easiest way to do these things.. How do I echo the respective value now? I tried to create a $variable = SELECT etc etc and then to simply echo it.. but I get something like "Resource id #41" instead of the value I am interested in.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the value in the `value` column of the row where `order_id` is 4, use this SQL:

```
$query = 'select value from options where order_id = 4';
```

Then you can access this result in many ways. One is to get the entire result row (which in this case is just one cell) as an associative array:

```
if ($result = mysql_query($query)) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo 'value = ' . $row['value'];
}
```

You can also get the value directly:

```
if ($result = mysql_query($query)) {
    echo 'value = ' . mysql_result($result, 'value');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would just be a query like...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM options WHERE ID = 3");
mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Unless Im misunderstanding you....let me know

But you really should use PDO, instead of deprecated mysql_* functions

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: pdo has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Yes it does, hes using deprecated functions....when things are deprecated, its best practice to move on to better and more secure options....its a helpful tip...if I didnt let him know, then how else would he learn

Comment: how do you know what version of php he's using ? what if this is for a homework assignment where he's expected to use `mysql_`? there's always a billion suggestions you could make to anyone posting amateurish code. i like to stick to answering the questions users actually ask. plus, using `mysql_` is a good way for beginners to learn the basics of interacting with mysql via php. it's far simpler than trying to learn about bound parameters and prepared statements at the same time. learning starts with the basics.

Comment: sorry, i just hate seeing that "use pdo!!!!" comment on EVERY mysql question. sometimes you just gotta let people figure out things on their own, i think.